# Skimage skeletonize or OpenCV implementation that respects a grid?

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, mathematical-morphology

Suppose one has lines intersecting each other at right angles.

[image: RightAngles]

And you would like to skeletonize it to obtain (you hope) a cross shape.  Instead, with `sklearn.morphology.skeletonize` the following image is obtained:

[image: Holey Cross]

Let's call it a "holey cross".

On the other hand, you have OpenCV and the OpenCV skeletonize function that is floating around on the internet in several blogs and answers on here:

```
def skeletonize(bin: numpy.ndarray, erosion_shape=cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernel_sz: Union[int, Tuple[int, int]] = 3):
    kernel_sz = fix_kernel(kernel_sz)
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(erosion_shape, kernel_sz)

    thresh = bin.copy()
    skeleton = numpy.zeros_like(bin)
    eroded = numpy.zeros_like(bin)
    carry = numpy.zeros_like(bin)

    while (True):
        cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, dst=eroded)
        cv2.dilate(eroded, kernel, dst=carry)
        cv2.subtract(thresh, carry, dst=carry)
        cv2.bitwise_or(skeleton, carry, dst=skeleton)
        thresh, eroded = eroded, thresh

        if cv2.countNonZero(thresh) == 0:
            return skeleton
```

This one produces the following result:

[image: Gap Cross]

---

So, there is something wrong or off about the basic OpenCV skeletonization function floating around, and the Skimage skeletonization cannot be modified with a structuring shape.

Is there a way to obtain the skeletonized cross/plus sign shape in python?

Comment: Looks like the snippet approximates the `skeleton` via `morphology`. Have you tried the "thinning" function on OpenCV's Extended Image Processing module? You call it like this: `skeleton = cv2.ximgproc.thinning(inputImage, None, algorithmCode)` where `algorithmCode` is `0` or `1`. More info on [the docs](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga37002c6ca80c978edb6ead5d6b39740c).

Comment: @eldesgraciado thanks man, I'll try that out tomorrow

Comment: scikit-image also has multiple methods, which give wildly different results on an image like this (having the source image would help). try `morphology.skeletonize(image, method='lee')`, `morphology.medial_axis(image)`, or `morphology.thin(image)`. In my attempts though none gave a perfect cross. But my test image was a little different from yours.

Comment: Cross-overs are hard to get right when skeletonizing because you would like the method to take some fairly non-local features into account. Notably, in your example, your central box is 8 pixels high, so the choice of medial pixel is ambiguous. For us humans that choice is obvious due to the thin arms extending outwards. After skeletonization, I typically fix such issues by [fitting hough lines](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_line_hough_transform.html).

Comment: @Juan thinned did the trick

Comment: @PaulBrodersen I wound up using hough lines to plumb-up the full image (everything is straight to within two pixels), but I had to use thinning to get the crisp cross-hatch to appear at the intersections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, you can clean up crossover points in a skeletonized image by fitting hough lines:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/q/66995948/2912349
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.transform import probabilistic_hough_line
from skimage.draw import line as get_line_pixels

img = np.zeros((20, 20))
img[4:16, 6:14] = 1
img[:, 10] = 1
img[10, :] = 1

skel = skeletonize(img)

lines = probabilistic_hough_line(skel, line_length=10)

# hough_line() returns the start and endpoint of the fitted lines;
# we need all pixels covered by that line;
cleaned = np.zeros_like(img)
for ((r0, c0), (r1, c1)) in lines:
    rr, cc = get_line_pixels(r0, c0, r1, c1)
    cleaned[rr, cc] = 1

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
axes[0].imshow(img, cmap='gray')
axes[0].set_title('Raw')
axes[1].imshow(skel, cmap='gray')
axes[1].set_title('Skeleton')
axes[2].imshow(cleaned, cmap='gray')
axes[2].set_title('Hough lines')
plt.show()
```

If you want to force horizontal or vertical fits, `lines` can be trivially filtered to exclude non-horizontal and non-vertical lines:

```
for ((r0, c0), (r1, c1)) in lines:
    if (r0 == r1) or (c0 == c1):
        ...
```